# Calling or not to abs() function, depending on template type being unsigned, if it is possible?

Tags: c++, templates

trying to compile code:

```
template<typename K, typename V>
typename ConcurrentMap<K, V>::Access ConcurrentMap<K, V>::operator[](const K &key) {
//    auto ind = abs(static_cast<long long>(key)) % bucket_count;
    auto ind = abs(key) % bucket_count;
    return {lock_guard<mutex>(mutexes[ind]), sub_maps[ind][key]};
}
```

and getting an error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'abs(const long long unsigned int&)' is ambiguous
```

Error is caused because of template parameter K being unsigned. Therefore, abs() cannot be called on it.

Can I disable calling to abs(), in case when template parameter K is unsigned?

Or please suggest some best-practice solution for such cases.
Thanks!

Comment: `if (key > 0)` Could you do something like that?

Comment: Add your own `abs` for unsigned types?

Comment: Does it really make sense to allow negative keys as input when `K` is signed? Why wouldn't you want to just always use unsigned keys and skip `abs()` altogether?

Comment: @RemyLebeau task assumes that K can be or signed either unsigned

Comment: @DynamicSquid I know, that such workaround is possible, but I'm learning c++, and just curious if possible to run different code based on type. But thanks for prompt :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename K, typename V>
typename ConcurrentMap<K, V>::Access ConcurrentMap<K, V>::operator[](const K &key) {
  K ind;
  if constexpr (std::is_unsigned<K>::value)
    ind = key % bucket_count;
  else
    ind = abs(key) % bucket_count;
  return {lock_guard<mutex>(mutexes[ind]), sub_maps[ind][key]};
}
```